# Rails Radio_button onchange reload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, radio-button, onchange

I have a website with two rating options (Likes and Stars), so I want to add a radio_button to choose which one should be load.

i have now this code:

```
<%= radio_button_tag 'receive_updates', 'no', true %> Likes
<%= radio_button_tag 'receive_updates', 'no', false %> Stars
```

After the radio_button state changed, I want to redirect to "root_path".

My Questions,

- How can I redirect after state changes WITHOUT a model?
- How can I control if likes are true or false?

I have found something to redirect like this:

```
<%= radio_button_tag 'receive_updates', 'no', true , :on_change => root_path%> Likes
```

but this on_change does not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure of what you want to do here but, using Javascript, you can redirect / pass params when "onchange" event is called like this:

```
<%= radio_button_tag 'receive_updates', 'likes', false %> Likes
<%= radio_button_tag 'receive_updates', 'stars', false %> Stars

<script >
    $(function(){
        $("input[name=receive_updates]").change(function(){
            var root_path = "<%= root_path %>"
            var url = root_path + "?receive_updates=" + $(this).val();
            window.location.replace(url);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: And how can I save the current state, is there a possibility to save it in the application controller ?

Comment: You can use the session storage as described here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#accessing-the-session

Comment: In your root controller, it may look like this `session[:receive_updates]=params[:receive_updates] if params[:receive_updates]` and in the view `<%= radio_button_tag 'receive_updates', 'likes', session[:receive_updates] == 'likes' %> Likes`

Comment: thank <ou so mutch first, now my last question, how to add this session in my application controller?

Comment: session is accessible by default in all controllers as described in RoR guide http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#session

Comment: Yes, it works like you told me => session[:receive_updates] thank you so much.